# Update form in xhtml file by id from another xhtml file

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, popup, xhtml

Here is my code

index.xhtml

```
<h1>Student List</h1>
    <h:form id="studentListForm">
        <h:dataTable id="studentsList"
                     style="border:2px solid;"
                     var="student"
                     value="#{tableItems.students}">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="First Name"/>
                <h:outputText value="#{student.firstName}"/>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="Last Name"/>
                <h:outputText value="#{student.lastName}"/>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="Faculty Name"/>
                <h:outputText value="#{student.faculty.name}"/>
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
        <br/>
        <p:commandButton value="Add Student"
                         update=":studentAdding"
                         oncomplete="PF('studentAddingDialog').show();"/>
    </h:form>
```

addStudent.xhtml

```
<p:dialog id="studentAddingDialogId" modal="true"
              header="Add Student"
              widgetVar="studentAddingDialog"
              closeOnEscape="true">

        <h:form id="studentAdding">
            <h:outputLabel value="Student first name"/>
            <h:inputText id="firstName"
                         value="#{tableItems.studentFirstName}"
                         required="true"/>
            <br/>
            <h:outputLabel value="Student last name"/>
            <h:inputText id="lastName"
                         value="#{tableItems.studentLastName}"
                         required="true"/>
            <br/>
            <h:outputLabel value="Choose student faculty"/>
            <h:selectOneMenu id="selectFaculty"
                             value="#{tableItems.studentFaculty}"
                             required="true">

                <f:selectItem itemLabel="--Select--" itemValue=""/>
                <f:selectItems value="#{faculties.faculties}"
                               var="itam"
                               itemValue="#{itam.name}"
                               itemLabel="#{itam.name}"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            <p:commandButton value="Submit"
                             actionListener="#{tableItems.addStudent}"
                             oncomplete="PF('studentAddingDialog').hide();"
                             update="studentListForm"/>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
```

After running the program I see an Error(HTTP Status 500 - Cannot find component for expression ":studentAdding" referenced from "studentListForm:j_idt10".) 
why it can't recognize the form with it's id from another xhtml file?

Answer (score 1):

Here you are trying to open a dialog that is located in another page, so when you try to update `studentAdding` it does not find the form, that explains the error `Cannot find component for expression ":studentAdding" referenced from "studentListForm:j_idt10"`, i suggest you include the page `addStudent.xhtml` in the main page that is `index.xhtml` :

```
<ui:include src="/../studentAdding.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="updateForm" value=":studentListForm"/>
</ui:include>
```

You have to make sure that anything that you want to update from `studentAdding.xhtml` and that is located in `index.xhtml`, you have to pass it as a parameter to `studentAdding.xhtml`, as an exemple `studentListForm` that you are updating in submit button, so when you update you use the name of the parameter that you passed, which is `updateForm`, like this :

```
<p:commandButton value="Submit"
                 actionListener="#{tableItems.addStudent}"
                 oncomplete="PF('studentAddingDialog').hide();"
                 update="updateForm "/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use any xhtml element from included xhtml file you can pass it as `<ui:param name="yourElementAlias" value=":pathTo:Element"/>`. It allows you to use this particular element from included source file:

```
<ui:include src="/../studentAdding.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="yourElementAlias" value=":pathTo:Element"/>
</ui:include>
```

Then, to use this element in studentAdding.xhtml (for example update it) do it like so:

```
<p:commandButton value="Submit"
             actionListener="#{tableItems.addStudent}"
             oncomplete="PF('studentAddingDialog').hide();"
             update="#{yourElementAlias}"/>
```